# Do thrust reversers make more noise than engine at same RPM?

Tags: noise, thrust-reverser

I'm talking about general aviation jet engines here. I live near an airport and I rarely listen engine noise on takeoff but always hear one during landing.

Would a jet engine at the same RPM make more noise when using thrust reverser than not using one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Most of the noise you hear from aircraft is not mechanical noise from engines but disturbances in airflow around the airframe and engine outlets and inlets.
The airflow from reversing jet engine is much more turbulent than when the engine is forward pushing and thus more noisy.